# push comment to facebook fanpage

Tags: php, facebook

Is there any tutorial on how I can push the comments made by the Facebook commentsbox to appear on my facebook fanpage??

I implemented the Commentsbox plugin on my webpage but the comments do not appear on my fanpage.

Thanks in advance.